# How to get shortcut id programmatically?

Tags: android

How to get the shortcutId programmatically?

I need to disable the shortcut based on the condition provided in below code, for that i need to get the shortcutId. not able to get the shortcutId

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_barcode_icon"
    android:shortcutId="bar_code"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcuts_my_bar_code">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW.myBarCode"
    />
</shortcut>

private static final String SHORT_CUT_MY_BARCODE = "android.intent.action.VIEW.myBarCode";

private void myBarCodeShortcut() {
    if (SHORT_CUT_MY_BARCODE.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        //todo need to get the shortcut id here and disable it.
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add data to app shortcut Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554349/how-to-add-data-to-app-shortcut-intent)

Comment: Please read my requirement. it's different.

Comment: No, it's not different. The shortcut triggers an `Intent`, and you want the `Intent` to carry any information needed to identify the 'source' of the `Intent`.

Comment: Another option is to get the list of all (static) shortcuts ([`getManifestShortcuts()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#getManifestShortcuts()) ) and find the `ShortcutInfo` which is associated with the Intent you received.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only receive an `Intent` from the shortcut, the `Intent` needs to carry all the information needed to identify its 'source'.

So whatever you do, the `Intent` must have some unique feature. This could be its "action", or any other data you can add.

One option to make the `Intent` unique is to include in the `Intent`s data the shortcut ID from which it was fired. (See e.g. [How to add data to app shortcut Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554349/how-to-add-data-to-app-shortcut-intent))

Another option may be to retrieve the list of all (static) shortcuts via [`ShortcutManager.getManifestShortcuts()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#getManifestShortcuts()) and find the `ShortcutInfo` object whose `Intent` matches the one you received. But again, this will of course only work if the `Intent` is actually unique to a given shortcut.

One more, and probably the intended, option is to have your code access the shortcut via its known ID, like you do with GUI elements.